# sql sorting algorithm with max and min func

Tags: sql-server, algorithm, t-sql, sorting

I have a table that has 1,2,3,4,5 numbers. How can I sort that way using T-SQL:

```
 5,1,2,3,4
```

- first row: max(Id)
- second row: min(Id)
- other rows: doesn't matter

but count rows have to 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way of doing it is to use `ORDER BY` with `CASE`:

```
SELECT id
FROM #t as t
ORDER BY CASE
           WHEN id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM #t) THEN 1
           WHEN id = (SELECT MIN(id) FROM #t) THEN 2
           ELSE 3
         END
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this.

```
SELECT top 5 t1.num
FROM SomeTable as t1, SomeTable as t2
GROUP BY t1.num
ORDER BY CASE
        WHEN t1.Num = MAX(t2.Num) THEN 1
        WHEN t2.Num = MAX(t2.Num) THEN 2
        ELSE 3
    END
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is yet another option. This is able to combine Min and Max into a single query. Not sure the performance benefit is much but if it is a large table it might help. The simplest solution is the one Giorgios posted. This one will have a **slight** edge on his excellent solution for performance.

```
with Something(SomeID, SomeValue) as
(
    select 1, 'Minimum' union all
    select 2, 'asdf' union all
    select 3, 'qwer' union all
    select 4, 'ljkh' union all
    select 5, 'Maximum'
)
, MinMaxVal as
(
    select MAX(SomeID) as MaxSomeID
        , MIN(SomeID) as MinSomeID
    from Something
)

select s.*
from Something s
left join MinMaxVal mmv on mmv.MaxSomeID = s.SomeID or mmv.MinSomeID = s.SomeID
order by MaxSomeID desc
    , MinSomeID desc
    , s.SomeID desc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
The Idea is to get the maximum and the remaining items in ascending order

Select  Tmax.*, -1 as zOrder From TbT as Tmax Where Tmax.ID = (Select Max(id) from tbt)
Union
Select Tmin.*, ID as zOrder From TbT as Tmin Where Tmin.ID <> (Select Max(id) from tbt)
Order by zOrder;
```

I just believe it could run faster on large data volume as max is computed only twice.